# Web scraping articles to see if new articles are posted

Tags: javascript, arrays, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I have an array of news updates coming from this website [here](https://www.newworld.com/en-us/news). What I am looking to do is `console.log` the latest news articles as they are published, or very close to when they are posted. With my code, I can send a request to obtain the articles, but I want to know when the array changes with a new entry.

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const express = require('express')
const PORT = 3000
const URL = 'https://www.newworld.com/en-us/news'
const splitURL = URL.slice(0, 24)

const app = express()

setInterval(() => {
    axios(URL)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const articles = []
        $('.ags-SlotModule', html).each(function(){
            const link = splitURL + $(this).find('a').attr('href')
            articles.push({
                link
            })
        })
        console.log(articles[0])
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}, PORT)

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server running'))
```

Additionally, I have not found any API or RSS feed I can use to obtain updates.

Comment: it changes when you do `articles.push`, what then do you want to do with it?

Comment: Nothing. I want it do nothing.

Comment: each of the articles has a url, use that to identify the page, then just make an object of objects which the key is the URL, then you wont get dupes and then scrape the data, each item has a date you can use the to order etc, also there is this url https://www.newworld.com/en-us/news-load-more?page=1 which has only the posts dom if you want to fire an event somewhere if something is changed make your object with Object.defineProperty and in set emit a EventEmitter (or use express events) though is unclear why your using express

Comment: Passing the `PORT` as the millisecond delay to `setInterval` might be a mistake.

Comment: Might be. Might not be.